# Custom Action Selector without Attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I would to create a custom action selector.

I have successfully done this by extending from `IControllerConfiguration` and `Attribute` however this requires decorating my services with a `[CustomActionAttribute]`.

I want to avoid this. I have a self-hosted web api service and would prefer to plug into  `HttpSelfHostConfiguration` eg. I want something like the following.

```
 new HttpSelfHostConfiguration(baseAddress)
      .ControllerConfiguration
      .Add(new CustomActionAttribute())
```

The above code is non working, but it describes the idea that I'm trying to get to.

I haven't seen any example to this extent or one that shows the right injection point to set the custom `IControllerConfiguration`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you want to do is register a custom action selector, you can do it right on the configuration object like this:

```
var config = new HttpSelfHostConfiguration(baseAddress);
config.Services.Replace(typeof(IHttpActionSelector), new MyActionSelector());
```

In general, anything you can do in controller configuration you should be able to do right on the global configuration object.